# search a keyword in postgresql json field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am currently using postgres 9.3.3

Following is how my table looks like -

```
 Column       |           Type           |                             Modifiers                              | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                 | integer                  | not null default nextval('playerbase_palyerdata_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 date_joined        | timestamp with time zone | not null                                                           | plain    |              | 
 belongs_to_camp_id  | integer                  | not null                                                           | plain    |              | 
 belongs_to_coach_id | integer                  | not null                                                           | plain    |              | 
 json_kvps          | character varying(2000)  | not null                                                           | extended |              |
```

One sample data is as follows -

```
id |      date_joined   | belongs_to_camp_id | belongs_to_coach_id | json_kvps

1  | 2014-03-07 18:10:45.824749+05:30 |                 1 |                  1 | {"alumnicode": "2003360009", "emailusername": "aaron@hotmail.com", "altemail": "", "salutation": "Mrs", "fname": "Aaron", "mname": "V", "lname": "Schwartz", "fullname": "Aaraon M Scwartz", "programmename": "MEP", "batchyearin": "2003"}
```

Now I want to search the entire table, and find a user with "emailusername":"aaron@hotmail.com"

As mentioned here - 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

I try to write a query as follows -

```
SELECT * FROM playerbase_playerdata WHERE json_kvps->>'emailusername' = 'aaron@hotmail.com';
```

I was expecting a column as above, instead I got the following error -

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying ->> unknown
LINE 1: ...ELECT * FROM memberbase_memberdata WHERE json_kvps->>'emailu...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Could someone please tell me, what am I missing?

Comment: "Could someone please tell me, what am I missing?" The postgres version number in the docs. Those operators added in 9.3. Some of the functions available from 9.2. But nothing in 9.1.

Comment: upgraded to version 9.3.3

Comment: Then reflect the correct version in the title & tags too. - for your problem: you must use the `json` type, not `text` nor `varchar`.

Comment: the table is being generated by django ORM. Any pointers how to specify json?

Comment: Cannot found anything here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/
But if you are able to run raw queries, you can alter its type to `json` after creation. - Also you can `CAST` to `json` at runtime queries, but that would make it slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feature like this exists only from PostgreSQL release 9.3.
So, unfortunately, to make queries like this you need to update your PostgreSQL.

If you have 9.3, then you need use json column type.

Here you can see some example. It helps me, earlier:
http://clarkdave.net/2013/06/what-can-you-do-with-postgresql-and-json/

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL 9.3 or higher, one possible solution could be using a cast to json:

> SELECT * FROM playerbase_playerdata WHERE json_kvps->>'emailusername' = 'aaron@hotmail.com';

`SELECT * FROM playerbase_playerdata WHERE CAST(json_kvps AS JSON)->>'emailusername' = 'aaron@hotmail.com';`

Answer (score 0):

In case of django models you can use JsonField.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/jsonfield.

It works fine, but if you'll use PostgreSQL version less than 9.2, it'll create character column.

Answer (score 0):

```
select [Required Fields] from  [Table Name] WHERE  [Column Name]::text = '{[Key]}' ::text
```